# cheapest way to get MS Windows virtual machine on mac?

Tags: windows-xp, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have an occasional need for an MS Windows machine (a few times a year).  My main machine is a Mac, and I'd like to get a cheap and legal MS Windows (XP or later) virtual machine that I can run on it.  I have VirtualBox installed already, and I don't want to use Wine or something like it.

If the cheapest way is to buy Windows XP CDs on eBay, I would appreciate clarification as to exactly which variant I need to buy as prices range from $10 to $260 and I find it all very confusing.  Is any version with a COA ok?  or does it need to explicitly say non-OEM, retail version, etc.?

Comment: We don't do shopping recommendations. Try to rephrase your question.

Comment: @Daniel: I would like to know what variants of Windows XP installation CDs available on eBay would allow me to legally create a VM on my Mac.

Comment: Sounds much better. Now just click the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/277819/edit) link and actually change your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

What-ever version you get a CAO is required as proof that it is (assuming it is!) a legitimate copy. If it is a used copy then you may have to go through the phone-in activation procedure in you install WGA in order to get the things that won't install without it - or you just might not be able to activate because going by the wording of the EULAs Windows licenses are not transferable (aside from OEM licenses which are intended to be transferred, once, to the user the manufacturer sells the resulting equipment to).